# Remove focus from EditView

Tags: android, xamarin, focus

I have EditText in which the user inputs some name then he clicks a button and I want the EditText to stop being focused and if the user taps with his finger I want it to be focusable again. I've tried all things on first page of Google results but nothing worked. Does anyone have some short solution, for example of one line. I can't believe Xamarin team didn't create this so important feature of removing focus from an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove focus from `edittext` like this:

```
yourParentLayout.requestFocus();
```

and inside `xml`

```
<yourParentLayout
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:focusable="true" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by yourParentLayout : the parent of all elements or the parent of my EditText?

Comment: means any linearLayout or RelativeLayout you can use